# Pycurl SSL Session ID not working, when provided with SSL keys

Tags: python, curl, libcurl, pycurl

By default libcurl (and pycurl) supports ssl connection resuse, meaning for a case of sending subsequent HTTPS requests, the second one will use the SSL session ID and avoid the full handshake. (basically `pycurl.SSL_SESSIONID_CACHE` is `True`).

When I testd it as:

```
import pycurl

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://myserver:443/X')
c.setopt(c.COOKIEFILE, '')
c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, True)

c.perform()

c.setopt(c.FRESH_CONNECT, 1)
c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://myserver:443/Y')
c.perform()
```

I can see that pycurl uses the session id for the second connection. However, once I added client key and CA info (for mutual auth), it stops working. Meaning, that the client negotiated a new SSL keys, which is undesirable.

```
import pycurl

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://myserver:443/X')
c.setopt(c.COOKIEFILE, '')
c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, True)
c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2)

c.setopt(c.SSLCERTTYPE, "PEM")
c.setopt(c.SSLKEYTYPE, "PEM")
client_cert = "ssl_keys/client/client_crt.pem"
ca_cert = "ssl_keys/ca/ca_crt.pem"
client_key = "ssl_keys/client/client_pr.pem"
c.setopt(c.SSLCERT, client_cert)
c.setopt(c.SSLKEY, client_key)
c.setopt(c.CAINFO, ca_cert)

c.perform()
c.setopt(c.SSL_SESSIONID_CACHE, True) # that doesn't matter really
c.setopt(c.FRESH_CONNECT, 1)
c.setopt(c.URL, 'https://myserver:443/Y')
c.perform()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curl disables "SSL session resumption" when client certificates are used for security purposes. See the [TLS session resumption client cert bypass](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/adv_20160803A.html) security advisory from August 2016 for specifics.

This feature *could* be made working even with client certificates but nobody has made the effort of writing the code for that to be done in a safe manner. I considered the use case to be small enough to take the easier route: disabling it for client certs.

Comment: aah... I see. Is there anyway you know that I can do that in python? none of the web client packages supports this. Anyway to trick pycurl for a work around?

Comment: The limitation is in libcurl, so you'd have to improve the libcurl code to make it work. Or use something that isn't libcurl-based that supports SSL session resumption.